# What exceptions can be thrown by exchange() on WebClient?

Tags: reactor-netty, spring-webclient

I've implemented a service which makes ReST calls out to other services to implement part of its functionality. I'm using the reactive `WebClient` for this, something like:

```java
webClient.post()
    .uri(....)
    .contentType(....)
    .accept(....)
    .header(....)
    .syncBody(someRequestObject)
    .exchange()
    .flatMap(someResponseHandler::handleResponse)
    .doOnError(throwable -> {
        // do interesting things depending on throwable
    })
    .retry(1, this::somePredicateDependingOnThrowable);
```

Now... I handle HTTP statuses in `someResponseHandler::handleResponse`, but what I really want to know is, what *other* kinds of exception/error to expect from the `exchange()` - i.e.

- what exceptions/errors do I get if I can't connect to the downstream service at all?
- What exceptions/errors do I get if the connection attempt times out?
- What exceptions/errors do I get if I can connect but then the request times out before I get a response?

None of these are HTTP status codes, obviously - but I can't find any documentation to tell me what I can look for. Am I just not looking in the right places? I've had a look through the documentation for the reactive WebClient, and I've had a look through the Reactor Netty Reference Guide, but no luck.

For background, this is important because we do HATEOAS-based service discovery - for some of these exceptions, I want to trigger rediscovery, for some of them, I don't.

Answer (score 5):

I recommend testing your code that uses the `WebClient` to see how it handles the various scenarios you mentioned.  You can test your code against something like [`MockWebServer`](https://github.com/square/okhttp/tree/master/mockwebserver) easily from unit tests. `MockWebServer` can simulate most of the errors mentioned here.

Having said that, here's what I have seen in my testing when using `WebClient` with the `ReactorClientHttpConnector`.  Other connectors may throw slightly different exceptions, but will likely share a super class in the exception class hierarchy as those mentioned below.

#### Unknown host

`java.net.UnknownHostException`

#### Connection refused (port not open on server)

`java.net.ConnectException` (or subclass)

reactor-netty throws `io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AnnotatedConnectException`

#### Connect timeout

If you have [configured a connect timeout](https://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/web-reactive.html#webflux-client-builder-reactor-timeout), then you will receive `java.net.ConnectException` (or subclass)

reactor-netty throws `io.netty.channel.ConnectTimeoutException`

#### SSL handshake errors

`javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException` (or subclass)

#### Request body encoding error

This varies by the encoder being used, but generally will be `org.springframework.core.codec.EncodingException` (or subclass)

Some encoders also throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException` if encoding is configured incorrectly

#### Response body decoding error

This varies by the decoder being used, but generally will be `org.springframework.core.codec.DecodingException` (or subclass)

Some decoders also throw `java.lang.IllegalStateException` if decoding is configured incorrectly

#### Read Timeout

If using reactor-netty, and you configured a `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutHandler`, then `io.netty.handler.timeout.ReadTimeoutException`

If you use the `.timeout` operator somewhere in the reactive stream call chain, then `java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException`

#### Write Timeout

If using reactor-netty, and you configured a `io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutHandler`, then `io.netty.handler.timeout.WriteTimeoutException`

#### Connection closed by server prematurely (before response completes)

`java.io.IOException` (or subclass)

reactor-netty throws `reactor.netty.http.client.PrematureCloseException`

#### Others

Any exceptions that occur during your `someResponseHandler::handleResponse`

Comment: Thanks. The difficulty with relying on my own tests to figure out what kinds of exceptions _can_ be thrown is that I will never know that I've caught every scenario. But ultimately, I think I came up with a very similar list to yours, just by looking at the bog standard Java exceptions that can be thrown when using sockets, etc.

Comment: Thank you! 

Can you add code to show us how to test these exceptions? I'm not able to figure out how MockWebServer can help me test WritetimeoutException and ConnectionTimeoutException.